# API gateway : Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-api-management

I have an issue with the embedded API management within a Cloud Foundry application ( node.js ) on bluemix .There is a certain path in the yaml which is not working via the gateway, please see below the relevant path from the yaml:

```
   /socket.io/:
get:
   produces:
    - text/plain; charset=utf-8
    parameters: []
    responses:
      default:
       description: Definition generated from Swagger Inspector
```

I get 404 , not found.

The url works fine when I dont go via the gateway.

The url is https://[masked api mgd hostname]/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MC0pE73

Please help.

Find attached the complete yaml below

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: defaultDescription
  version: "0.1"
  title: defaultTitle
host: masked.actualEndpoint
schemes:
  - https
basePath: "/"
paths:
  /socket.io/:
    get:
      parameters:
      - name: t
        in: query
        required: false
        type: string
        x-example: MC0pE73
      - name: EIO
        in: query
        required: false
        type: string
        x-example: "3"
      - name: transport
        in: query
        required: false
        type: string
        x-example: polling
      responses:
        default:
          description: Definition generated from Swagger Inspector
definitions: {}
```

am accessing the url using https://[ masked api mangd hostname ]/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MCvtHJT

I believe its the / at the end of the path ( /socket.io/ ) which is causing the gateway to fail. Any comments.

Comment: can you please provide your full yaml file and curl example of the path that is not working?

Comment: updated with yaml details